# SAAS based application , want to have only one layout page for all modules

Tags: angular, layout, saas

I have different sites developed in angular but i want to have one layout for all my websites.

Is there any possibility to use same layout page for all my websites, so design of layout can be same with-out doing it in each site?

Comment: this may help full for you.
https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see multiple ways going with that:

## Solution 1

Create a stylesheet/component library and reuse that anywhere. [Really nice guide here](https://medium.com/@Dor3nz/compiling-css-in-new-angular-6-libraries-26f80274d8e5) / [docs here](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)

## Solution 2

Combine multiple applications in one. Based on the url, load the appropriate application, which can be developed almost independently. [Excellent guide with the same rationale as the one you are trying to achieve](https://octoperf.com/blog/2019/08/22/kraken-angular-workspace-multi-application-project/)

For more specifics, please provide some code so that we can expand on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should extract common layout and stylings as an angular library and reuse it for every app.
More details:
https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries